How to setup a custom SSL certificate for a local ASP.NET Core Web API on Windows?
I'm developing an ASP.NET Core Web API and running it locally from a docker container using a self-signed certificate generated with OpenSSL. Everything works as expected when SSL certificate validation is disabled in Postman, but requests fail with SSL validation enabled. The browser also shows a "Your connection is not private" error.
Here's how I generated the certificate:
Generated a private key:
openssl genrsa -out localhost.key 2048

Created a Certificate Signing Request (CSR):
openssl req -new -key localhost.key -out localhost.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=State/L=City/O=Organization/OU=Unit/CN=localhost"

Generated a self-signed certificate:
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in localhost.csr -signkey localhost.key -out localhost.crt

Converted the .crt and .key files to a .pfx file for Kestrel:
openssl pkcs12 -export -out localhost.pfx -inkey localhost.key -in localhost.crt -password pass:yourpassword

I've configured Kestrel in Program.cs to use the .pfx file:
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ListenAnyIP(32769, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps("localhost.pfx", "yourpassword");
    });
});

I've also imported the .crt file into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store using certlm.msc.
Despite this, Postman fails when SSL certificate validation is enabled, and the browser still warns that the connection is not private.
Questions

How can I fix the issue in Postman with SSL certificate validation enabled?
Why does the browser still display a privacy error after importing the .crt file?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
What I've tried

Verified the Common Name (CN) in the certificate matches localhost
Imported the .crt file into the trusted root store


What is the exact error message the browser displays? Post all the error information. Also, include at least the hostname portion of the URL you are using to connect in your browser.

The browser show "Your connection is not private" is because of "SAN"(Subject Alternative Names) isn't set, which need to the same as CN and a litte tricky to be configured. This is my step:
At begining, openssl.cnf needn't be configured, you could use default
1.openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
2.Openssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca.csr -config openssl.cnf
3.openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ca.csr -signkey ca.key -out ca.crt
4.openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
5.openssl req -new -out server.csr -key server.key -config openssl.cnf
Now you need configure openssl.cnf to add SAN to continue https://easyengine.io/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/ssl/multidomain-ssl-subject-alternative-names/:
6.openssl ca -in server.csr -out server.crt -cert ca.crt -keyfile ca.key -extensions v3_req -config openssl.cnf
7.openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey server.key -out private_certificate.pfx
Finially use the private_certificate.pfx is server certificate and make sure ca.crt is in the trust root, then there will be no warning.

SNI and the subject alternative name are different things. The usual abbreviation for subject alternative name is SAN.
